# How to fix "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid number of parameters for"

Tags: ethereum, solidity, abi

I get "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid number of parameters for ..." error but I'm passing correct number of parameters. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason leads to this problem is using SOLC 0.5.8. It has a bug which produces incorrect abi sometimes. Downgrading to 0.5.7 fixed the problem for me.